# Find the measure of the angle from the data in the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have to find $\angle AMN$ of the triangle $\triangle ABM$ below.
[image]

The triangle $\triangle ABM$ is isosceles. I know that $\angle AMN+\angle BMN=180^{\circ}-2\cdot50^{\circ}=80^{\circ}.$ From the picture, we get $\angle MAN=40^\circ$ and $\angle ABN=30^{\circ}.$ Also, $\angle ANB=180^{\circ}-10^{\circ}-30^{\circ}=140^{\circ}$ in $\triangle ABN.$ But I don't know how to find $\angle AMN.$ What can I use to find it?

Comment: Math_algebra, what have you tried? You  should write more context in your post.

Comment: Are you given that $~\angle NAB = 10^\circ,~$
as suggested by your diagram?  Also, are you 
given that $~\angle NBM = 20^\circ,~$ as 
suggested by your diagram?

Comment: Is $AM=BM=a$? Then the base angles should be same.

Comment: $\angle AMN=70\unicode{176}$.

Comment: It's given. @user2661923

Comment: If the answers to the two questions in my previous answer are both *Yes*, then, the problem should be routinely conquerable via Analytical Geometry.  First, assume that $~a = 1,~$ and compute $~b~$ via the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).  Then, assign the Cartesian coordinate of $~(0,0)~$ to point $~A,~$ and (in effect) the Cartesian coordinate $~(b,0)~$ to point $~B.~$  Now, the Cartesian coordinate of point $~M~$ is determined, and the problem reduces to computing the Cartesian coordinate of point $~N.$  ...see my next comment

Comment: Here, the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) should be helpful.  There will probably be a more elegant and easier approach.  However, if all else fails, the Cartesian Coordinates approach should work.

Comment: This is a problem for kids in elementary school. They don't know what are sin and cos.@user2661923

Comment: How did you find it? @Angelo

Comment: "This is a problem for kids in elementary school.": I would still make Cartesian Coordinates my *first line of attack*.  This will allow you to determine the answer.  Then, knowing what the answer *has to be*, you can attempt to **reverse-engineer** how to construct a Geometric proof that will establish the answer.

Comment: Math_algebra, if you add more context to your question and write all you have tried, I will write a complete answer.

Comment: @Angelo I rewrote angles I know how to determine, but I don't know where to start with $\angle AMN.$ Maybe to prove $AM=AN,$ but I don't know how. I can't notice two similar triangles or two congruent triangles.

Comment: @math_algebra, I have already written a complete answer, read it and tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to solve the exercise.

[image: Exercise]

Since the triangles $\,AEK\,$ and $\,AEH\,$ are congruent by ASA Criterion, it results that $\,EK\cong AH\,.$

Moreover the triangles $\,ABM\,,\,BME\,$ and $\,ANE\,$ are isosceles and the triangle $\,BEK\,$ is half an equilateral triangle, consequently,

$AM\cong BM\cong BE\cong 2EK\cong 2AH\cong AN\;\;,$

hence,

the triangle $\,AMN\,$ is isosceles too and

$\angle AMN=\dfrac{180\unicode{176}-\angle MAN}2=70\unicode{176}\,.$

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions.

## Synthetic geometry

[image]

Let $P$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABN$.  Since
$$
\angle APN = 2 \angle ABN = 60^\circ,
$$
we have $AN = AP$.  Since
$$
\angle APB = 2 (180^\circ - \angle ANB) = 80^\circ,
$$
the quadrilateral $AMBP$ is a rhombus, so $AP = AM$.
Therefore, $AN = AM$, so
$$
\angle AMN = \frac{180^\circ - \angle MAN}{2} = 70^\circ.
$$

## Trigonometry

Assume that $AM = BM = 1$, so $AB = 2 \sin 40^\circ$.  Applying the law of sines in $\triangle ABN$ shows that
$$
AN = 2 \sin 40^\circ \cdot \frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin 140^\circ} = 1,
$$
so
$$
\angle AMN = \frac{180^\circ - \angle MAN}{2} = 70^\circ.
$$

Comment: Thanks! It's a good idea to describe a circle around the triangle $ABN$.

Comment: @math_algebra The intuition that led me to circumscribe a circle around $\triangle ABN$ was the cancellation $\sin 140^\circ = \sin 40^\circ$ that powered the trigonometric solution, which I developed first.  $\angle ABN = 30^\circ$ was a telltale sign too.  By the way, in case you didn't know, accepting one answer would automatically unaccept other answers, so you would have to pick one.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT.** I posted this answer too quickly, but I'll leave it up as in incomplete answer. As noted in the comments, this system is underdetermined, so there is a $1$-parameter infinite family of solutions. (The matrix associated to the system has rank $3$.) Hence, we need one more piece of information to determine the angles.

---

Let's give shorter names to four of the angles:
\begin{align}
w &= \angle AMN \\
x &= \angle BMN \\
y &= \angle ANM \\
z &= \angle BNM 
\end{align}

Then using the fact that the sum of all three angles in a planar triangle is $180^\circ$ and the sum of all angles around a point is $360^\circ$, we can write down four linear equations. *Try it yourself before revealing the spoiler.*

> $$\left\{ \begin{aligned} w + x &= 80 \\ y + z &= 220 \\ w + y &= 140 \\ x + z &= 160 \end{aligned} \right.$$

Hopefully, you can take it from here.

Comment: Please note that the system is underdetermined.

Comment: I didn't downvote but, as L. F. indicated, for example, adding your first $2$ equations gives the same result as adding the last $2$ equations, so they're not all linearly independent.

Comment: D'ohhhhh, true!

Comment: The system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer to reflect this shortcoming, and I'll leave it up as a hint *towards* a solution.

Comment: @SammyBlack  Before you do that, you might consider whether the hint actually does lead towards a solution.